Superadmin login is asking for staff account
I am trying to create a custom user model in my Django project.
Here are my code:
models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager



############# Handles the creation of regular users and
#  superusers (admin users) with custom logic. ############
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    # Creates a regular user with the necessary fields
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have a username')
        
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),    # This line normalizes the email address 
                                                    #that means it converts the domain part of the email address to lowercase.
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    # Creates a superuser with the necessary fields
    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, password=None): 
        user = self.create_user( # This line calls the create_user method to create a regular user. 
            email = self.normalize_email(email), 
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_superadmin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




    
     
######################## This is a custom user model that represents a user
# with fields that go beyond the default Django user model.#################
class Account (AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    # Required fields for the AbstractBaseUser class.
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # This field is automatically set when the object is first created.
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) # This field is automatically set when the object is updated.
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # This field is used to determine if the user has administrative privileges.
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' # This line makes sure that user will login using email instead of username.
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name'] # These fields are required when creating a user.

    objects = MyAccountManager() #  In Django, the objects attribute is the default manager for model queries
                                # to get all accounts). By setting objects = MyAccountManager(), you replace the default manager
                                # with a custom one, MyAccountManager. In summary, this line ensures that the Account model uses the MyAccountManager for database operations, enabling custom user creation logic.


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    
    def has_module_perms(self, add_label):
        return True

admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Account

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Account)

settings.py:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
I have successfully created a super user. But when I am trying to login 'Django Administration', it is showing the message "Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."
I have used "pip install django==3.1" when downloading Django.
I have provided correct email and password. Also I have attempted several times by deleting db.sqlite3 and migrating from scratch but could not find any way.

are you sure user object true that both in is_staff and is_admin?

I am following a tutorial and it was so like this. I dont know actually. Can you tell me how it is supposed to work?

In your create_superuser method you're not passing the password to the create_user method, so your user is created with a raw password of None, which is an unusable password.

Also, support for Django 3.1 stopped 2021. Consider using any of the supported versions.
